# Copy files/folders between site collection and retaining metadata

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, metadata

I'm using SharePoint 2013

I need to copy files/folders/sub folders from one site collection to different site collection(basically archiving them).

I need to do this remotely by using CSOM/JSOM. Can we maintain metadata after copied files / folders? If so, please share some code.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell Script to dump all the folders from one list to another in same or different site collection with metadata . Try it on sample list and test first .

```
function Copy-ItemsToFolder([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder]$folder, $srcList, $destList)
{
$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$spQuery.Folder = $folder


$sourceSPListItemCollection = $srcList.GetItems($spQuery);
$destFolder = $destList.Folders[$folder.Name];
if ($destFolder -eq $null -or $destFolder -eq "")
{
    #folder does not exist so create it.
    $destFolder = $destList.AddItem("", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder)
    $destFolder["Title"] = $folder.Name ;
    $destFolder.Update()
}
$count = $sourceSPListItemCollection.Count;
$index = 0;
$newFolderPath = $destFolder.Folder.ServerRelativeUrl
foreach($srcListItem in $sourceSPListItemCollection)
{
    $index++;

    write-host "adding new item $index of $count";
    $newSPListItem = $destList.AddItem($newFolderPath, [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::File, $null);

    foreach($spField in $srcListItem.Fields)
    {
        if ($spField.ReadOnlyField -ne $True -and $spField.InternalName -ne "Attachments")
        {
            $newSPListItem[$spField.InternalName] = $srcListItem[$spField.InternalName];
        }
    }
    $newSPListItem.Update()
    write-host "added";
}
}
try
{
$srcListSiteUrl = "https://sitename/abc/"
$SourceListName = "lsitname"

$dstListSiteUrl = "https://sitename/def/"
$DestinationListName = "lsitnamearchieve"

$keyColumnInternalName = "Title"

$sourceListWeb = Get-SPWeb -identity $srcListSiteUrl
$sourceListUrl = $sourceListWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/" + $SourceListName;

$dstListWeb = Get-SPWeb -identity $dstListSiteUrl
$destinationListUrl = $dstListWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/" + $DestinationListName;

$SourceList = $sourceListWeb.GetList($sourceListUrl);
$DestinationList = $dstListWeb.GetList($destinationListUrl);

foreach($currentFolder in $SourceList.RootFolder.SubFolders)
{
    Write-Host "processing folder $($currentFolder.Name)";

    if ($currentFolder.ItemCount -gt 0)
    {
        Copy-ItemsToFolder $currentFolder $SourceList $DestinationList
    }
    Write-Host "done with folder"
}

}

catch
{
write-host $_.exception
}

finally
{
if($sourceListWeb -ne $null){$sourceListWeb.Dispose()}
if($dstListWeb -ne $null){$dstListWeb.Dispose()}
}
```

Comment: Thx for taking time to respond. Let me implement and let you know how it worked for me.

Comment: Just a quick reminder: you need to have all the fields from the source list in the destination list.